# Calculate the number of ways to roll a certain number

Tags: java, algorithm, probability, combinatorics

I'm a high school Computer Science student, and today I was given a problem to:

> Program Description:  There is a belief among dice players that in
>   throwing three dice a ten is easier to get than a nine.  Can you write
>   a program that proves or disproves this belief?
>
> Have the computer compute all the possible ways three dice can be
>   thrown: 1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 1 + 2, 1 + 1 + 3, etc.  Add up each of these
>   possibilities and see how many give nine as the result and how many
>   give ten.  If more give ten, then the belief is proven.

I quickly worked out a brute force solution, as such

```
int sum,tens,nines;
    tens=nines=0;

    for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=6;j++){
            for(int k=1;k<=6;k++){
                sum=i+j+k;
                //Ternary operators are fun!
                tens+=((sum==10)?1:0);
                nines+=((sum==9)?1:0);
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("There are "+tens+" ways to roll a 10");
    System.out.println("There are "+nines+" ways to roll a 9");
```

Which works just fine, and a brute force solution is what the teacher wanted us to do. However, it doesn't scale, and I am trying to find a way to make an algorithm that can calculate the number of ways to roll *n* dice to get a specific number. Therefore, I started generating the number of ways to get each sum with *n* dice. With 1 die, there is obviously 1 solution for each. I then calculated, through brute force, the combinations with 2 and 3 dice. These are for two:

> There are 1 ways to roll a 2
>  There are 2 ways to roll a 3
>   There are 3 ways to roll a 4
>  There are 4 ways to roll a 5
>   There are 5 ways to roll a 6
>  There are 6 ways to roll a 7
>   There are 5 ways to roll a 8
>  There are 4 ways to roll a 9
>   There are 3 ways to roll a 10
>  There are 2 ways to roll a 11
>   There are 1 ways to roll a 12

Which looks straightforward enough; it can be calculated with a simple linear absolute value function. But then things start getting trickier. With 3:

> There are 1 ways to roll a 3
>  There are 3 ways to roll a 4
>   There are 6 ways to roll a 5
>  There are 10 ways to roll a 6
>   There are 15 ways to roll a 7
>  There are 21 ways to roll a 8
>   There are 25 ways to roll a 9
>  There are 27 ways to roll a 10
>   There are 27 ways to roll a 11
>  There are 25 ways to roll a 12
>   There are 21 ways to roll a 13
>  There are 15 ways to roll a 14
>   There are 10 ways to roll a 15
>  There are 6 ways to roll a 16
>   There are 3 ways to roll a 17
>  There are 1 ways to roll a 18

So I look at that, and I think: Cool, Triangular numbers! However, then I notice those pesky 25s and 27s. So it's obviously not triangular numbers, but still some polynomial expansion, since it's symmetric. 
So I take to Google, and I come across [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68045/rolling-dice-such-that-they-add-up-to-13-is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-solve) that goes into some detail about how to do this with math. It is fairly easy(albeit long) to find this using repeated derivatives or expansion, but it would be much harder to program that for me. I didn't quite understand the second and third answers, since I have never encountered that notation or those concepts in my math studies before. Could someone please explain how I could write a program to do this, or explain the solutions given on that page, for my own understanding of combinatorics?

EDIT: I'm looking for a mathematical way to solve this, that gives an exact theoretical number, not by simulating dice

Comment: This seems almost a little off-topic, since you are looking for a mathematical solution which (presumably) you are happy to code once you know what you're doing. As a result, it doesn't seem to really be a programming question at its heart.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution using the generating-function method with `N(d, s)` is probably the easiest to program.  You can use recursion to model the problem nicely:

```
public int numPossibilities(int numDice, int sum) {
    if (numDice == sum)
        return 1;
    else if (numDice == 0 || sum < numDice)
        return 0;
    else
        return numPossibilities(numDice, sum - 1) +
               numPossibilities(numDice - 1, sum - 1) -
               numPossibilities(numDice - 1, sum - 7);
}
```

At first glance this seems like a fairly straightforward and efficient solution.  However you will notice that many calculations of the same values of `numDice` and `sum` may be repeated and recalculated over and over, making this solution probably even less efficient than your original brute-force method.  For example, in calculating all the counts for `3` dice, my program ran the `numPossibilities` function a total of `15106` times, as opposed to your loop which only takes `6^3 = 216` executions.

To make this solution viable, you need to add one more technique - memoization (caching) of previously calculated results.  Using a `HashMap` object, for example, you can store combinations that have already been calculated and refer to those first before running the recursion.  When I implemented a cache, the `numPossibilities` function only runs `151` times total to calculate the results for `3` dice.

The efficiency improvement grows larger as you increase the number of dice (results are based on simulation with my own implemented solution):

```
# Dice | Brute Force Loop Count | Generating-Function Exec Count
3      | 216 (6^3)              | 151
4      | 1296 (6^4)             | 261
5      | 7776 (6^5)             | 401
6      | 46656 (6^6)            | 571
7      | 279936 (6^7)           | 771
...
20     | 3656158440062976       | 6101
```

Comment: This is great, but I'm unfamiliar with the HashMap object. Could you show me how it is done in this case and direct me to a place where I can learn about them?

Comment: You could also use a two-dimensional jagged array to store them.  For example, the possible inputs for `sum` are `numDice - 6*numDice`.  So instantiate an array with ranges `[1][1-6]`, `[2][1-12]`, `[3][1-18]`, etc. up to the number of dice you are calculating results for.  For an introduction to `HashMap` you might try http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-collections.html

Comment: Thanks. This gave me everything I wanted for this, and I was able to figure out how to use the memoization and understand the code without further explanation, so thank you for teaching me.

Comment: @mellamokb I'm struggling to understand how your algorithm works. Could you extend your answer to explain it a little?

Comment: @Duncan: It may not have been clear, but the OP refers to another question on Math.SE (in the last paragraph) where this problem is treated more rigorously.  I modeled the programming solution on [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/68057/2704) - I'll defer to that post for a better explanation than I could do :)

Comment: @mellamokb Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but the method you developed doesn't return the number of ways to roll for example 1 die to get a specified sum. All it gives me is a StackOverflowException when run. Any suggestions? Let's say, for an extremely simple example, I roll 1 die and I wish to find ways to get a sum of 2. Then it would be {1,1} and {2}, so a total of 2 ways.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to brute force since your first roll determines what values can be used in the second roll, and both first and second roll determine the third roll. Let's take the tens example, suppose you roll a `6`, so `10-6=4` meaning you still need `4`. For the second roll you need at least `3`, because your third roll should at least count for `1`. So the second roll goes from `1` to `3`. Suppose your second roll is `2`, you have `10-6-2=2`, meaning your third roll IS a `2`, there is no other way.

Pseudo code for tens:

```
tens = 0

for i = [1..6] // first roll can freely go from 1 to 6
   from_j = max(1, 10 - i - 6) // We have the first roll, best case is we roll a 6 in the third roll
   top_j = min(6, 10 - i - 1) // we need to sum 10, minus i, minus at least 1 for the third roll
   for j = [from_j..to_j]
      tens++
```

Note that each loop adds 1, so at the end you know this code loops exactly 27 times.

Here is the Ruby code for all 18 values (sorry it's not Java, but it can be easily followed). Note the min and max, that determine what values can have each of the dice rolls.

```
counts = [0] * 18

1.upto(18) do |n|
  from_i = [1, n - 6 - 6].max # best case is we roll 6 in 2nd and 3rd roll
  top_i = [6, n - 1 -1].min # at least 1 for 2nd and 3rd roll
  from_i.upto(top_i) do |i|
    from_j = [1, n - i - 6].max # again we have the 2nd roll defined, best case for 3rd roll is 6
    top_j = [6, n - i -1].min # at least 1 for 3rd roll
    from_j.upto(top_j) do
      # no need to calculate k since it's already defined being n - first roll - second roll
      counts[n-1] += 1
    end
  end
end

print counts
```

For a mathematical approach, take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4632/how-can-i-algorithmically-count-the-number-of-ways-n-m-sided-dice-can-add-up-t

Comment: How does this scale as you increase the number of dice?  Is it just 6^(d-1) instead of 6^d?

Comment: @mellamokb see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4632/how-can-i-algorithmically-count-the-number-of-ways-n-m-sided-dice-can-add-up-t

Answer (score 2):

Mathematical description is just a 'trick' to make same counting. It uses polynomial to express dice, `1*x^6 + 1*x^5 + 1*x^4 + 1*x^3 + 1*x^2 + 1*x` means that each value 1-6 is counted once, and it uses polynomial multiplication `P_1*P_2` for a counting of different combinations. That is done since coefficient at some exponent (`k`) is calculated by summing all coefficient in `P_1` and `P_2` which exponent sum to `k`.

E.g. for two dices we have:

```
(1*x^6 + 1*x^5 + 1*x^4 + 1*x^3 + 1*x^2 + 1*x) * (x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x) = 
(1*1)*x^12 + (1*1 + 1*1)*x^11 + (1*1 + 1*1 + 1*1)*x^11 + ... + (1*1 + 1*1)*x^3 + (1*1)*x^2
```

Calculation by this method has same complexity as 'counting' one.

Since function `(x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x)^n` has simpler expression `(x(x-1)^6/(x-1))^n`, it is possible to use derivation approach. `(x(x-1)^6/(x-1))^n` is a polynomial, and we are looking for coefficient at `x^s` (`a_s`). Free coefficient (at `x^0`) of `s'th` derivation is `s! * a_k`. So, `s'th` derivation in 0 is `s! * a_k`.

So, we have to derive this function `s` times. It can be done using derivation rules, but I think that it will have even worse complexity than counting approach since each derivation produces 'more complex' function. Here are first three derivations from Wolfram Alpha: [first](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivate%20%28x%28x-1%29%5E6/%28x-1%29%29%5En%20by%20x), [second](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivate%20n%20%28-1%2bx%29%5E4%20%28%28-1%2bx%29%5E5%20x%29%5E%28-1%2bn%29%20%28-1%2b6%20x%29%20by%20x) and [third](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivate%20%28n%20%28%28-1%2bx%29%5E5%20x%29%5En%20%28-1%2bn%20%281-6%20x%29%5E2%2b2%20x-6%20x%5E2%29%29/%28%28-1%2bx%29%5E2%20x%5E2%29%20by%20x).

In general, I prefer counting solution, and mellamokb gave nice approach and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Monte Carlo Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) they usually scale linearly with inputsize. In this case the example is easy, we assume that since once throw of the dice doesn't affect the other instead of counting combinations we can simply count the sum of the faces of dices thrown randomly (many times enough).

```
   public class MonteCarloDice {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> histogram;
    private Random rnd;
    private int nDice;
    private int n;

    public MonteCarloDice(int nDice, int simulations) {
        this.nDice = nDice;
        this.n = simulations;
        this.rnd = new Random();
        this.histogram = new HashMap<>(1000);
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        for (int simulation = 0; simulation < n; simulation++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < nDice; i++) {
                sum += rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
            }
            if (histogram.get(sum) == null)
                histogram.put(sum, 0);
            histogram.put(sum, histogram.get(sum) + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(histogram);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MonteCarloDice(3, 100000);
        new MonteCarloDice(10, 1000000);
    }

}
```

The error decreases with number of simulations but at the cost of cputime but the above values were pretty fast.

3 dice

```
{3=498, 4=1392, 5=2702, 6=4549, 7=7041, 8=9844, 9=11583, 10=12310, 11=12469, 12=11594, 13=9697, 14=6999, 15=4677, 17=1395, 16=2790, 18=460}
```

10 dice

```
{13=3, 14=13, 15=40, 17=192, 16=81, 19=769, 18=396, 21=2453, 20=1426, 23=6331, 22=4068, 25=13673, 24=9564, 27=25136, 26=19044, 29=40683, 28=32686, 31=56406, 30=48458, 34=71215, 35=72174, 32=62624, 33=68027, 38=63230, 39=56008, 36=71738, 37=68577, 42=32636, 43=25318, 40=48676, 41=40362, 46=9627, 47=6329, 44=19086, 45=13701, 51=772, 50=1383, 49=2416, 48=3996, 55=31, 54=86, 53=150, 52=406, 59=1, 57=2, 56=7}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a more mathematical solution to this

Comment: Monte Carlo methods are mathematical, don't let the simplicity deceive you ;) posted this as an alternative for the hard math. They are heavily used to simulate problems that are too difficult to find the direct analytical solutions to (or too inefficient).

Comment: I think the OP's brute force method is better. 1) It gives an exact answer. 2) You have to do *many* more simulations than brute-force iterations to get a "good" distribution. I notice for 3 dice you're simulating 100k throws and your answer is still a bit wild, while the OP's is only doing 216 sums.

Comment: Sure but try the brute force or the recursive case for 100 dices, this goes as O(simulations * dice) while the bruteforce is n^dice and the recursive case seems to be going O(n^5). You are of course entitled to your downvote but a case like this is inherently made for montecarlo.

Comment: Just look at your `n=10,sims=1000000` case. You're showing the probability of rolling a `[10,11,12]` are all the same, zero. This is *clearly* not close to true. In fact, the number of ways you can roll an `11` is *ten times* the number for `10`. The reason for this is because you're doing less simulations than possibilities(6^n), so they can't *possibly* all be covered at the right ratio. It's the same reason you can't just flip a coin once to decide whether it's a "fair" coin. You need to flip it *at least* a hundred times.

Comment: I'm not saying that Monte Carlo methods are useless, I'm just saying that this is **not** an "inherently made" case for it.